# EventListener is not being added to button elements

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

I have a list of products, each product having an `id` and `item` property. I have to add a remove button for every item. With every click of the remove button, that product should be removed.

I'm trying to loop though the list and for each product I'm creating a `button` element and setting its `id` attribute to the `id` of the product.

However, for some reason, the event listener is not getting added to the buttons except the last button (`button#5`) .

Below is the JS code I have written..

```
const div = document.body.querySelector('div');

let products = [
    {
        id: "1",
        item: "Shirt"
    },
    {
        id: "2",
        item: "Jeans"
    },
    {
        id: "3",
        item: "T-shirt"
    },
    {
        id: "4",
        item: "Denim Jacket"
    },
    {
        id: "5",
        item: "Casual Shoes"
    }
];
const removeItem = (itemId) => {
    products = products.filter((prod) => {
        return prod.id !== itemId;
    })
    console.log(products)
    updateDom();

}
function updateDom() {
    div.innerHTML = '';
    div.style.padding = '20px';

    for (let prod of products) {
        let btn = document.createElement('button');
        btn.id = prod.id;
        btn.textContent = 'Remove';

        btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
            removeItem(btn.id);
            console.log(btn.id);
        })
        div.innerHTML += `<li>${prod.item}</li> `
        div.appendChild(btn);

    }
}

updateDom();
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div></div>
    <script src="prac.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Above is the `html` code where I'm trying to append the `li`  and the `button` elements to the `div`. Why is the event listener only getting added to the last button element and not to every buttons? Am I missing something here? Thankyou for your time.

Comment: `div.innerHTML +=`  is the reason only the last buttons event listener remains

Comment: i.e. when you change `innerHTML`, the elements inside that element are replaced - therefore any event listeners on them will be lost

Comment: @JaromandaX but shouldn't the event listeners remain because I'm using the += operator which appends content to the previously existing content of div? I'm not replacing the content of 'div' but rather adding more to it.

Comment: `I'm using the += operator` yes, and you are assigning a value to innerHTML - doesn't matter how you do it, the result is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the `Jaromanda X` description, I give my solution:

```
function updateDom() {
    div.innerHTML = '';
    div.style.padding = '20px';

    for (let prod of products) {
        let btn = document.createElement('button');
        btn.id = prod.id;
        btn.textContent = 'Remove';

        btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
            removeItem(btn.id);
            console.log(btn.id);
        });
        let li=document.createElement("li");
        li.textContent=prod.item;
        div.appendChild(li);
        div.appendChild(btn);

    }
}
```

Comment: to be honest, I'd write it a little different so that `updateDom` would only ever have to be called once :p I'd call `removeItem` with `btn` and `li` arguments, and use `btn.remove()` and `li.remove()` to update the DOM